# Getting specific data from Fact

Tags: prolog

I know that the Title ,does not mean anything , however , how to get 'calculas1' word and put it in list  from this fact using prolog :

```
 hasMark(calculas1 , 78 , 110).
```

Comment: When you say "put it in a list" do you mean you have an existing list? Or you want to make a list of all the subjects?

Comment: @mbratch i want to save 'calculas1' in an empty list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Prolog, you can query a fact this way:

```
hasMark(Subject, X, Y).
```

Which, in the case of your example, would yield:

```
Subject = calculus1
X = 78
Y = 110
```

The easiest way to collect them would be using the builtin, `findall`:

```
findall(Subject, hasMark(Subject, _, _), Subjects).
```

This will yield:

```
Subjects = [calculus1, ...]
```

The `...` are other subjects, if you have them. Notice that I used `_` for two of the parameters. That means I don't care what those values are. Any variable that starts with a `_`, including that character by itself, means "don't care".

You can also use a predicate like this:

```
add_subject( MyList, [Subject | MyList] ) :-
    hasMark(Subject, _, _).
```

So you can query:

```
add_subject( [], List ).
```

And get:

```
List = [calculus1].
```

Note that a naming convention with underscores and lower case is more commonly used in Prolog than "camelCase". So it would be preferred to name your facts `has_mark`.